# explicit specialization of a class that inherits from a virtual class

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, c++-templates

I have a virtual class `BASE`, and an inherited class `BOX_str`which implements the virtual functions

```cpp
class BASE {
public:
    virtual ~BASE() {};

    virtual std::vector<int> custom_int() const = 0;

    virtual std::vector<double> custom_double() const = 0;
};

struct BOX_str final : public BASE {

    template <typename ...Args>
    BOX_str(Args... args) : base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    std::string base;

    std::vector<int> custom_int() const {
        return custom_vec<int>(base);
    }

    std::vector<double> custom_double() const {
        return custom_vec<double>(base);
    }

    template <typename NUM>
    std::vector<NUM> custom_vec(const std::string& s) const {
        return {32, 62};
    }
};
```

But all of the `BOX_str` class content, except for the `custom_vec()` function, is generic amongst similar classes,

so I've tried to make a template class `BOX`

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct BOX : public virtual BASE {

    template <typename ...Args>
    BOX(Args... args) : base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

    T base;

    std::vector<int> custom_int() const {
        return custom_vec<int>(base);
    }

    std::vector<double> custom_double() const {
        return custom_vec<double>(base);
    }

    template <typename NUM>
    std::vector<NUM> custom_vec(const T&) const;
};
```

and leave `custom_vec()` to be implemented later for each explicit specialization of `BOX`

```cpp
template <>
struct BOX<std::string> {
    template <typename NUM>
    std::vector<NUM> custom_vec(const std::string& s) const {
        return {42, 52};
    }
};
```

then I tried to test the classes

```cpp
int main() {
    std::string mystr{ "abcd" };

    BASE* v1 = static_cast<BASE*>(new BOX<std::string>(mystr));
    BASE* v2 = static_cast<BASE*>(new BOX_str(mystr));
}
```

`v2` didn't raise any errors, but `v1` did: `excess elements in struct initializer`, which means the the explicit specialization of `BOX` cannot access its constructor, and all of `BOX`'s contents.

I'm quite stuck and can't figure out how to correctly implement the `BOX` class so that it would work like `BOX_str` but in a generic manner. Would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Why do you make the constructor a variadic template ? `BASE` constructor do not take any argument so it's useless to forward arguments for any derived class since nothing, except no argument, is eligible.

Comment: Moreover, a specialization is not a derived class. The specialization **replaces** the generic definition (in other words, what you really want is a "subderived" class, not a specialization).

Comment: You can't do partial specialization of classes or structures. You must do a complete, full reimplementation.

Comment: Terminology: `BASE` is an **abstract class** because it has (one or more) **pure virtual functions**. The term "virtual class" doesn't really mean anything, and could be confused with "virtual base".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, any problem* can be solved by an additional abstraction layer:

Define `BOX::custom_vec` to call a yet-to-be-defined `::custom_vec`:

```
template <typename T>
struct BOX : public virtual BASE {
    // [...]

    template <typename NUM>
    std::vector<NUM> custom_vec(const T& v) const {
        return ::custom_vec<T, NUM>{}(v);
    }
```

Then, provide a struct that can be specialized and fully redefined without useless duplication of code:

```
template<class BoxT, class BoxN>
struct custom_vec {};

template<>
struct custom_vec<std::string, int>
{ std::vector<int> operator()(std::string const&) const { return {42, 52}; } };

template<>
struct custom_vec<std::string, double>
{ std::vector<double> operator()(std::string const&) const { return {1.618, 3.14}; } };
```

[Demo on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/1daqs94aj)

---

<sub>*except having too many abstraction layers</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the solution, what does the empty double colons `return ::custom_vec<T, NUM>{}(v)` mean?

Comment: This is the scope "operator". It makes the name lookup switche from unqualified name lookup to qualified name lookup. Here, the effect of the switch is to find `custom_vec` from the global namespace instead of `BOX::custom_vec`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide the full definition of the `BOX` class again in your specialization, not just the `custom_vec()` function:

```cpp
template <>
struct BOX<std::string> : public virtual BASE {

    BOX(const std::string& s) : base(s) {}

    std::string base;

    std::vector<int> custom_int() const {
        return custom_vec<int>(base);
    }

    std::vector<double> custom_double() const {
        return custom_vec<double>(base);
    }

    template <typename NUM>
    std::vector<NUM> custom_vec(const std::string& s) const {
        return {42, 52};
    }
};
```

Comment: That's what i'm trying to avoid, the definition of all `BOX`s contents except for the function that does change between the classes which is `custom_vec()`

Comment: Defining the `custom_vec()` method in a specialized version of the `BOX` class, as you've tried to do, won't work. When you specialize the `BOX` class for `std::string`, you are creating a completely new class that doesn't inherit anything from the original `BOX` template. This is why the constructor and other methods are not available in your specialized `BOX<std::string>` class.